# mutate_each in dplyr: create new column with the mean row values of other columns with some text in common

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to insert new columns with mean values of other existing columns starting with a specific text?

For example, in this data set:

```
zz <-("
id  20_1    20_2    20_3    22_1    22_2    22_3    
1   .      4.00     3.50    5.80    5.35    5.15    
2   3.50    .       3.30    5.65    5.40    5.05    
3   2.80    3.40    3.80    5.30    5.25    5.30    
")

df <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

I´d like to create two new columns 20_4 and 22_4 with the mean row value of the 20_1:20_3 and 22_1:22_3 respectively...

```
id  20_1    20_2    20_3    20_4    22_1    22_2    22_3    22_4
1   NA      4.00    3.50    3.75    5.80    5.35    5.15    5.43
2   3.50    NA      3.30    3.40    5.65    5.40    5.05    5.37
3   2.80    3.40    3.80    3.33    5.30    5.25    5.30    5.28
```

Could someone help me with that? I´m still learning dplyr...

Comment: Do you really have `.` in your data or are you trying to mimic `NA` ?

Comment: Thanks! edited question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this would be using 'summarize' in dplyr to create the variables you want

```
zznew<-zz %>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  summarize("20_4"=mean(`20_1`:`20_3`,na.rm=TRUE),"22_4"=mean(`22_1`:`22_3`,na.rm=TRUE))%>%
  left_join(zz,zznew,by="id")
```

Edit: In retrospect think I am incorrect in saying to use 'summarize'. Here is a different way that will calculate the means for each row for the selected columns and bind them to the dataframe:

```
zzz<-cbind(zz,"20_4"=rowMeans(zz[,c("20_1","20_2","20_3")],na.rm=TRUE),
      "22_4"=rowMeans(zz[,c("22_1","22_2","22_3")],na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: There´s something wrong because it´s giving 20_4 = (2, 3, 2.5) when It should be 20_4 = (3.75, 3.4, 3.33)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer to add a different method that should work

Comment: this is a good solution out of dplyr... I thought it could be easy with mutate_each(), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution for this would probably be using Non-Standard Evaluation:

Let's consider a df similar to yours:

```
zz = data_frame(
  `20_1` = rnorm(5),
  `20_2` = rnorm(5),
  `20_3` = rnorm(5),
  `22_1` = rnorm(5),
  `22_2` = rnorm(5),
  `22_3` = rnorm(5)
)
```

1. First we create a character vector with the name of the columns we want to average together. The following code will dynamically select all the column names starting with 20_:

   ```
   to_aggregate = names(zz)[grepl("^20", names(zz))]
   ```
2. We create a formula that dynamically calculate the mean:

   ```
   agg_formula = as.formula(paste0(" ~ mean(c(", paste0("`", to_aggregate, "`", collapse = ", "), "))"))
   ```

   this will create the formula: 
   ~ mean(c('20_1', '20_2', '20_3'))
3. We can use dplyr to go row by row and apply the dynamic formula generated above:

   ```
   zz %>% 
     mutate(tmp_ID = row_number()) %>% 
     group_by(tmp_ID) %>% 
     mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(agg_formula), 'res')) %>% 
     mutate(check_res = (`20_1` + `20_2` + `20_3`) / 3) %>% 
     ungroup()
   ```

Comment: It´s giving me this error... `r Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:13: unexpected input
1:  ~ mean(c(20_
                ^ `

Comment: Yeah you get the error because the column names have invalid names so you need to wrap them with a \`. I changed the agg_formula now to have the "`" before and after the row name and it will work now